# Подключение к apache cassandra

Tags: база-данных, apache, сервер, cassandra

Столкнулся с такой проблемой,как удаленно подключаться к БД Apache cassandra?Допустим у меня есть запущенная БД на одном пк,могу ли я как-то подключиться к данной БД удаленно с другого пк?Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Ответ - да, но нужно правильно сконфигурировать...